# Add elements to a vector in R with while loop

Tags: r, while-loop

Suppose my vector is as follow:

```
fruit = c("apple", "orange")
```

I sample one fruit at a time and store the chosen fruit in a vector.

```
chosen=sample(fruit, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
```

Suppose I want to continue sampling until the total number of oranges is 2 more than that of apples, but I'm having trouble with combining all my samples into a single vector.

```
i = 1
keepgoing = TRUE
while(keepgoing){
  i=sample(fruit, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
  i+1=sample(fruit, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
  fruitlist=rbind(i, i+1)
  if(sum(fruitlist=="orange")-sum(fruitlist=="apple")==2){
  keepgoing = FALSE}
  i = i +2
  }
```

Comment: I find it easier to generate `n` oranges, `n+k, k > 2` apples, then concatenate them and permute them. It can avoid loops.

Comment: Ex: `x <- c(rep("oranges", 5), rep("apples", 8)); x[sample(13)]`. You can generalise this.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I stop sampling as soon as I have 2 more oranges than I have apples?

Comment: Could you add that as an answer @Arun?

Comment: @Bonnie you would not, you specify how many elements you want the end vector to have. Next you create a vector with the required number of elements, with 2 more oranges that apples. Finally, you just randomly mix the vector.

Comment: This means that your sample vectors will always be the same size, in contrast to the sample vector created iteratively (see my answer). This size depends on how long it takes for the number of oranges to be two more than the number of apples. What do you need?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I don't know how many elements I want the end vector to have. If I keep on drawing apples, say 5 in a row, then I must draw 7 oranges in a row in order to stop sampling. However, if I were to draw another apple in the process, then I must draw a total of 8 oranges to satisfy oranges-apples=2. As soon as oranges-apples=2, I must stop sampling right away. So it's impossible for me to know how many elements the end vector has.

Comment: @Bonnie, as your output, do you need a vector of apples and oranges e.g. `c("apple", "orange", "orange", "orange")` or can you just store how many of each was drawn, e.g. `num.apples = 1` and `num.oranges = 3`? The latter will be a lot easier as it does not require a growing object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sample units are independent (probability of later units does not depend on the probability of the earlier units, always being 0.5 in this case), we can use another strategy. Instead of growing the sample, we can draw a large(r) sample first, and then cut it off at the point where our desired condition is satisfied:

```
makeSample <- function(n=20) {

    fruit <- c("apple", "orange")

    full.sample <- sample(x = fruit, size = n, replace = TRUE)
    apples  <- cumsum(full.sample == "apple")
    oranges <- cumsum(full.sample == "orange")
    diff <- oranges - apples

    exit.position <- match(2L, diff)
    if (is.na(exit.position))
        stop("The condition specified not achieved, try again or increase N")
    result <- head(full.sample, exit.position)
    return(result)
}
```

The function is simple really. It draws a large (superset) sample of the desired length, default is 20. Two logical vectors are created (`full.sample == "orange"` and `full.sample=="apple"`), the amount of apples and oranges in each successive step is calculated with `cumsum()`, since TRUE is equal to 1 (fruit present) and FALSE to 0 (fruit absent). Then we take the difference between those vectors and see whether at any point that difference satisfies our condition. If yes, the function returns the resulting sample you originally wanted. If not, it throws the error urging you to try again or increase N.

This should be more efficient on larger samples, and it can be easily adjusted to more complex conditions. When N is small, there is a chance you won't get the result, as opposed to the loop solution. Your chances are approaching 1 as N increases. You could wrap `makeSample()` in another function which would make sure you always get the result.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion of @Arun is really what you want, but your while loop example would look something like:

```
keepgoing = TRUE
all_fruit = NULL
while(keepgoing) {
   next_piece_of_fruit = sample(fruit, 1, TRUE)
   all_fruit = c(all_fruit, next_piece_of_fruit)
   if (sum(all_fruit == "orange") - 
       sum(all_fruit == "apple")) == 2) keepgoing = FALSE
}
```

Do note that you are growing a vector inside a loop here, which can become veeeery slow for large amounts of sampling...

Comment: In that case, you better pre-allocate say 1000, then resize to 2000, 4000, etc. as needed. You could even sample 1000, 1000, 2000, etc. at a time and cut where the cumulative sums start differing by `2`. Finally, I would store a vector of booleans to save space.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you need to use `rbinom`. Assuming `orange` = `1` and `apple` = `0` :

```
set.seed(56)
fruit.sample <- c()
while(TRUE)
{
    fruit.sample <- c(fruit.sample, rbinom(1,1,0.5))

    if (sum(fruit.sample==1) == sum(fruit.sample==0)+2)
        break
}

fruit.sample
## [1] 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

Basically the idea to stop sampling once `Num.Oranges` = `Num.Apples + 2`. If you repeat the experiment with different seed, you will get different result.